# Swift vs JavascriptCore perf

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, performance, javascriptcore

I am working on new end point (iOS) of a product. It has web presence. Several components (business logic) would be needed in iOS too. I am trying to weigh the benefits of JS code reuse over reimplementing business logic in Swift.
To measure perf, I executed bubble sort with hard coded data of size 10. Same code (except syntactic sugar) was written in Swift and JS. JavascriptCore library was used to execute code written in a .js file.

```
if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TestPerf", ofType: "js") {
            do {
            // Load its contents to a String variable.
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)

            // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
            context.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)

        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I did two experiments. Both were repeated 5 times. One, run bubble sort

```
for i in 1...5 {
    testPerfOneIteration(context: self.jsContext) <-------- Same JSContext every time
}
```

> one iteration in ms     .
>   Swift:  0.09500980377197266 JS: 
>   1.0221004486083984
>
> Swift:  0.04100799560546875 JS:  0.1609325408935547
>
> Swift:  0.0400543212890625 JS:  0.11491775512695312
>
> Swift:  0.03910064697265625 JS:  0.1291036605834961
>
> Swift:  0.03898143768310547 JS:  0.10800361633300781

Two, run bubble sort 10k times and note total elapsed time .

> 10k iterations in ms
>   Swift total time taken:  432.3619604110718 JS
>   total time taken:  1050.1370429992676
>
> Swift total time taken:  405.10010719299316 JS total time taken: 
>   1043.8190698623657
>
> Swift total time taken:  396.6749906539917 JS total time taken: 
>   1031.238079071045
>
> Swift total time taken:  399.82903003692627 JS total time taken: 
>   1010.8669996261597
>
> Swift total time taken:  419.8509454727173 JS total time taken: 
>   1007.6370239257812

In the first experiment, it can be seen that JS perf was 10x of Swift in first run and 2.5 - 4x in subsequent runs. In the second experiment, JS perf was consistently around 2.5x of Swift.

**Questions:**
1. Why does JS perf varies in first and subsequent runs? Does JS engine do byte code caching? What kind of JS component/environment setup is done by Swift?
2. Currently same JSContext is being passed in every call. Would it make any difference if JSContext is created before each call?
3. Is it expected that JS code execution would always be slower than the one in Swift? Is it recommended to execute JS code from Swift if the performance is that (2.5x) bad?
4. How cumbersome is JS debugging story when it's clubbed with Swift?

Comment: Javascript is typically run in a JIT-compiled, garbage compiled environment. There's absolutely no reason to expect consistent run-times. Also, make sure you're using release builds with all/most optimizations turned-on. It's surprising that Swift is only 2.5x slower, I would expect something more like 25x or 250x.

Comment: You mean Swift is 2.5x faster, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant 2.5x faster (at least). Particularly in bench marks that don't warm up the JIT.